# NullPointerException when creating Custom Dialog box in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-dialog

I have a main layout in which I have a search button.
The result is showed in tablelayout which in another layout named layout1.
Now when I click on one row, I want to show details about that row in a custom dialog box. 
I have layout named info in which i have a textview which i need to populate at run time. but when I try to settext the application crashes with NullPointerException

Any idea as to why this could be the case?

Thanks.

Comment: looks like your textview is null. Make sure that it's exists in XML.

Comment: We can't help you unless you post the code !!

Comment: Just paste your code so that we can see what exactly is happening...